# Control multiple print of message based on database results

Tags: php

After following some answers and articles finally i came up with  the function that will generate key(number) automatically when it is not exist in the database and codes works, but the problem is when the code exist the notification that "CODE EXIST" form something like a loop and print multiple notifications. Base on my codes where do i get it wrong and how can I fix it?

```
    <?php
 //HERE IS THE FUNCTION  
      function MyFunction($xIsConnection){
    // CODE GENERATION
      //$Code=(rand(10,1000));
       $Code='001';
       $query= "SELECT * FROM parent WHERE code='$Code'";
        if($result= mysqli_query($xIsConnection,$query)){
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
       echo " CODE EXIST<br>";

  // CALL FUNCTION TO GENERATE NEW CODE
         MyFunction($xIsConnection);
            }
       else{
       echo "NOT EXIST  <br>";
       echo $Code;
         }
        }
    else{
    echo"failed";
    }
    }
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    MyFunction($con);
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: Did you setup a connection(`$con`)?

Comment: yes i did @ WasteD,  as @Mr. Laststringx  said below i see that is the problem but i don't have how can i get out of it? any idea with code example.

Comment: Where does this funtion generate code? It just sets `$code` but doesnt do something with it.

Comment: below  the comment " CODE GENERATION" there  is the commented line "$Code=(rand(10,1000));"  that is the one generate i use set $code so that i can test the result with the existing value in the database@ WasteD

Comment: Alright you check if a code in the database exist. And then you generate a new one? What is the reason for that?

Comment: concept is like watsapp creating access code and  send via sms  @WasteD sorry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

The answer is never ending recursion.

```
<?php
     //HERE IS THE FUNCTION  
          function MyFunction($xIsConnection){
        // CODE GENERATION
          //$Code=(rand(10,1000));
           $Code='001';
           $query= "SELECT * FROM parent WHERE code='$Code'";
            if($result= mysqli_query($xIsConnection,$query)){
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           echo " CODE EXIST<br>";

      // CALL FUNCTION TO GENERATE NEW CODE
             MyFunction($xIsConnection);         // this line is responsible for your error. Recursion
                }
           else{
           echo "NOT EXIST  <br>";
           echo $Code;
             }
            }
        else{
        echo"failed";
        }
        }
        require_once('dbConnect.php');
        MyFunction($con);
        mysqli_close($con);

        ?>
```

Comment: so how can i control it because that is the function to auto generate code if   the previous generated one exist in database? is there any way to achieves it?  @Mr. Laststringx

Comment: Use aniother function to check if it exist in database. Store the result in a boolean variable and then check its value. @f2k

Comment: if am not out of what you have said  i created this "<?php
function MyFunction($xIsConnection){
$Code=(rand(10,1000));
//$Code='001';
$query= "SELECT * FROM parent WHERE code='$Code'";
if($result= mysqli_query($xIsConnection,$query)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
echo $Code;
}
 }
 else{
echo"failed";
 }
}
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$MyFunctionResult=MyFunction($con);
if($MyFunctionResult== true)
{
 echo "exist";
}
else{
 echo "not exist";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>"   but how can i  check its value ? @ Mr. Laststringx

Comment: i checked if code exist and return true, but how can i check values since it seems to be i will fall under the use of the same problem for reuse the same function @ Mr. Laststringx

Comment: Either 
• export all the codes in a set from the database and then generate a code which is not there in the set.
• or generate a set of codes and then check for it's existence in the database. (This can cost you some time)